# How to update the jquery FullCalendar appointment after i have created the event

Tags: jquery

what is the event or method name that i have to call or handle to update an existing event in the calendar(the event i click on). full calendar can be found here http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you initialize the FullCalendar instance, bind the eventClick handler:

```
var calendar = $('#calendar');
var curr_event = null;
calendar.fullCalendar({
    ...

    events: [],
    eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
        curr_event = event;
        show_form_or_something();
    },

    ...
});
```

You might want to show a form or something in order to allow the user to modify the event properties (title, start etc). Then to update the event back in the FullCalendar instance:

```
$.extend(curr_event, {
    title: 'New Event Title',
    start: new Date()
});
calendar.fullCalendar('updateEvent', curr_event);
```

And to address jmeho question:

When you add the event to FullCalendar either through `renderEvent()` or event source, you can specify `id` for each event. After you added the event, you can retrieve the event hash/object by using:

```
var event_obj = calendar.fullCalendar('clientEvents', 'specific event id');
```

Then you can modify the has/object and use the updateEvent() method to update the FullCalendar display.

Answer (score 1):

This code is perfect for update the calendar after update the event.
First remove date event, then render it again.

```
function updateCalenderUP(id, title, Sessiontitle, SessionStart, Sessionend, color) {    
    title = title;
    var id1 = id;

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'removeEvents', id1);
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refresh');
    title = title; 

    if (title) {
        calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
                id: Eventid,
                title: title,
                start:startDate,
                end: EndDate,                                
                allDay: false,
                backgroundColor:color
            }, true // make the event "stick"
        );
    }
    calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
}
```